# What is "Delete Connection" in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3cuV.png)

I've loaded databases from several servers. But I want to clean my Database Navigator now.

If I click the Delete Connection, will all the database, table, data in server be deleted? or just disconnect only?

Answer (score 0):

It will delete the connection (that is the line between you and said database) only.